# getting total entries of descendants and total from another table

Tags: php, laravel

Good day artisans!

I'm working on to get the total entries of my descendants and deduct their withdrawals. I use laravel-adjacency-list which is working fine (thanks to @staudenmeir).

I want to deduct the total withdrawals of every descendant to the sum of their entries.

This is my code right now which only get the total entries

```
$referrals = User::find($user->id)->descendants()->whereDepth('<', 20)
    ->addSelect(['amount' => Entries::select('amount')
    ->whereColumn('user_id','laravel_cte.id')
    ->orderBy('created_at')
    ->limit(1)
])->where('active',1)->get();
```

The main goal is SUM the total entries, and sum total withdrawals and subtract total withdrawals to the total entries of the user.

Answer (score 0):

I have updated my code. I'm also getting the total withdrawals now using the below code, now my problem is how can I subtract the `total_withdrawal` to the `total_entries` and sum all the answers of that into `grand_total`

```
$referrals = User::find($user->id)->descendants()->whereDepth('<', 10)
->addSelect(['total_entries' => Entries::selectRaw('sum(amount) as entries')
    ->whereColumn('user_id','laravel_cte.id')
    ->orderBy('created_at')
    ->limit(1)
])
->addSelect(['total_withdrawal' => Withdrawal::selectRaw('sum(amount) as withdrawal')
    ->whereColumn('user_id','laravel_cte.id')
    ->groupBy('user_id')
])->where('active',1)->get();
```